# XCTest: XCode crashes on swipe

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

I try to record a swipe on a collection view with the latest XCode Version (7.2). XCode than crashes immediately:

```
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): ancestorFinder is not being processed by childNodeFinders. 

currentNodeFinder:<XCUIRecorderNodeFinder: 0x7fed29660780>allowDirectChildrenMatches:0, targetElementType:XCUIElementTypeOther, ancestorNodeFinderMatch:0x7fed315a53e0

ancestorFinder:<XCUIRecorderNodeFinder: 0x7fed2967b800>allowDirectChildrenMatches:1, targetElementType:XCUIElementTypeCell, ancestorNodeFinderMatch:0x7fed315aa580
```

Can someone tell me how to perform a swipe on a collectionview so that I can create my UI-Test?

Comment: Got the same problem. Do you have any solution?